# TypeConverter usage in Camel

Tags: apache-camel

I need to develop a Camel Route where data has to be transformed in a different data format.

Camel offers multiple solutions for that:

- Managing the different data format at the Endpoint level (if I am writing the endpoint)
- Registering and using typeConverters
- Explicitely add on a route a processor which performs the conversion

What are the benefits and the drawbacks of the different approaches?

Answer (score 0):

It's common practice to register a type converter method which can be used when you get the reference of camel context and exchange, and you can use Message.getBody(class) to turn the message body to the data format you want if there is a type converter for the transformation.

If you manage the data formats at the endpoint level, you cannot expose the data format handling method to other camel components just like registering a type converter. But it could be useful if you just want to use these data formats inside of the endpoint.

If you write a processor to perform the conversion, you have to add the processor to the route yourself and it's not handy if you want to do the conversion in multiple place.